# What exactly is (alert(1),"") in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss

I tried doing google gruyeres XSS challenges (http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/part2), and at the stored AJAX XSS challenge they have the following code part for the JSON response:

```
all <span style=display:none>"
+ (alert(1),"")
+ "</span>your base
```

The interesting part is: `(alert(1),"")`

According to the solution provided, the empty string gets returned. According to my testing, the alert(1) still gets exectued.

Is this some sort of function shorthand, or what would this be called in JS?
Why does it execute the alert, but then return the empty string?

Thank you very much for any help!

Best regards,
Rolf

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: @DaveNewton thank you very much, this was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [comma operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-Comma-Operator-in-JavaScript). The code executes `alert(1)`, discards its return value, then evaluates `""`. Since this is the last item in the expression, its value is returned, which is empty string.

The tutorial I linked describes it as follows:

> The comma operator in JavaScript evaluates each of its operands. It returns the value of the last operand. Add multiple expressions using the comma operator.

Comment: thank you very much for that clear and simple answer!